# Is a person guilty of theft if they hold a sincere but mistaken belief that they own the stolen property?

Tags: theft, mens-rea

Alice believes, on good reason, that an item belongs to her, but in fact it belongs to Bob. If Alice attempts to take the item for herself, is she guilty of theft? What if Alice already has the item and Bob attempts to take it back; can Alice legally use force to protect herself and her "property"?

Comment: In England and Wales this would fail the "dishonesty" and "intention to permanently deprive the other" parts of the test for theft under Section 1 and 6 of the [Theft Act 1968](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60), so there would be no theft. However, if Alice subsequently discovers that she was wrong to believe it belonged to her and then decides to keep it anyway, that could amount to theft.